# nativescript switch size larger

Tags: angular, typescript, switch-statement, nativescript

I have this html code:

.HTML

```
 <Switch style="margin-top: 10" (checkedChange)="onFirstChecked1($event)" row="0" col="1" horizontalAlignment="center" class="m-15 firstSwitchStyle"></Switch>
```

.CSS

```
.firstSwitchStyle{
    width: 30%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

I want to make bigger switches.

Any idea please?

Comment: I don't think it's possible via CSS. You will have to define your own drawables / shapes for the switch from your Android Theme. An easy hack is to play with `scaleX` / `scaleY` but it might need fixed width and height to be set, alignment may be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the size of a switch in nativescript using CSS. You need to use native methods to play with the size. I have created a sample playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=390rcn).

I have tested that on ios and it is working fine. You need access the nativeElement of Switch and in the loaded method like the following
in html

```
<Switch #mySwitch checked="true" class="m-15 firstSwitchStyle"
                (loaded)="switchLoaded($event)"></Switch>
```

and in your .ts

```
declare let CGAffineTransformMakeScale: any; // or use tns-platform-declarations instead of casting to any


@ViewChild('mySwitch') mySwitch: ElementRef;

switchLoaded(args) {

        let mySwitch = this.mySwitch.nativeElement;
        if (isIOS) {
            let iosSwitch = mySwitch.nativeView;
            iosSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3, 3);
        }
    }
```